# drawing curve on google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to draw curves on google map.
When I searched about it, I found that there is an attribute called "geodesic" is set to true to enable the drawing of curve, but when I use it, it draws a line which is not curved.
Here is what I did.
I just set the geodesic to true

```
var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
path: flightPlanCoordinates,
geodesic: true,
strokeColor: '#FF0000',
strokeOpacity: 1.0,
strokeWeight: 2
});
```

Here is the full code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple Polylines</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script>

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, -180),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
  map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(45.56117947133065,-122.5868225097656));


  var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(45.56117947133065,-122.5868225097656),
    new google.maps.LatLng(45.493833740092185,-122.6348876953125)
  ];

  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The referenced fiddle is using `GmapsCubicBezier` to draw a curved line.  [{geodesic:true} does curve the polyline, but you don't see it at small scales](http://jsfiddle.net/t146qLzz/).

Comment: Isn't there a solution to make it appear at small scales?

Comment: Why can't you use `GmapsCubicBezier` like the fiddle you posted?

Comment: I didn't use GmapsCubicBezier in the fiddle, or maybe i am not understanding you

Comment: The [fiddle in your question](http://jsfiddle.net/skhbq2vz/4/) is either one of my examples or a copy of one of my examples that draws a curved polyline using `GmapsCubicBezier`.

Comment: It was a mistake, sorry.
I have edited the post with  my code that doesn't work